# Conditional object creation using java Supplier interface

Tags: java, performance, java-8

I have a method as below:

```java
void updateObject(ObjOne obj, SomeClass data) {
    if(obj != null) {
        obj.doSomething(data);
    }
}
```

The `updateObject` is called many times and to avoid null check at each place, I thought of avoiding the below:

```java
// directly invoke doSomething conditionally.
if(obj != null) {
    SomeClass data = getData();
    obj.doSomething(data);
}
```

Since `data` is used only when `obj` is non null, I thought of refactoring the code as below:

```java
void updateObject(ObjOne obj, Supplier<SomeClass> data) {
    if(obj != null) {
        obj.doSomething(data.get());
    }
}
```

This would create an object of `SomeClass` only when required, but instead creates an object of `Supplier` type.

Is the above approach using `Supplier` better?

Comment: if your question is : "is lazily getting the BigData object better then getting eager it all the time since it's very expensive to get it", then the answer is obvious.

Comment: “Better” is a subjective term. When you assume the creation of the `BigClassObj` to be more expensive than the creation of a `Supplier`, then you already said everything that can be said about it. We can only take your word.

Comment: Of course, the outcome depends on how often `obj` is `null`. When it is non-`null` most of the time, you’ve just added the creation of a `Supplier` without a benefit.

Comment: @Holger I have updated the question to be more general, than just for a bigger object

Comment: you have not changed your question fundamentally after your edit. The answer is still the same - _if_ getting that Object is _really_ that expensive and it is _really_ that often null - yes, that is better. For obvious reasons that you already know.

Comment: But now, we have even less information to give an answer. If you are designing an API, offering both methods, `updateObject(ObjOne obj, SomeClass data)` and `updateObject(ObjOne obj, Supplier<SomeClass> data)` and let the caller who knows about the expenses decide, is the best option. If it is an internal method and you know the expenses and likelihoods, make the decision for either method.

Comment: If you cache  and use the same supplier `Supplier<SomeClass> sup = () -> getData();` Then it won't create supplier every time.

Comment: @onkarruikar this is most probably a `public` method, a `Supplier` will be passed by the callers.

Comment: @onkarruikar As Eugene said, it would be passed by the caller.

Comment: @Holger, Yes I think that would be the better option, to have two methods so that the caller can take a decision depending on that use case.

Comment: every time I think the same at my workplace - "I'll let the caller decide, he/she is a reasonable person that will read the javadoc", the exact opposite happens. Every single time, the stupid decision is taken. I stopped having faith in these kind of things lately

Comment: @Eugene :-) Will Supplier approach be worse than passing the object itself? If it is not, then won't it be better to go with the Supplier approach itself?

Comment: you already have an answer from one of the most knowledgeable person in the Java APIs that I am aware of, so my opinion is irrelevant.

Comment: @GauthamM most of the time, the performance impact of the `Supplier` creation would be negligible, but it’s *syntactic* overhead when forcing the caller to provide a supplier when not needed. And people will continue to ask you “why do I have to do this”…

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The performance depends on the costs of the construction of the `SomeClass` instance, in other words, what you can save when only creating a `Supplier` and never a `SomeClass` instance, and the likelihood of not creating the `SomeClass` instance. If the `SomeClass` instance is created anyway in most cases, you obviously can’t save anything by additionally creating a `Supplier`.

If you are designing an API without knowing the expenses and likelihoods, you may offer both methods and let the caller decide which to use. That is an established pattern, e.g.

- [`Objects.requireNonNull​(T obj, String message)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T,java.lang.String)) vs
- [`Objects.requireNonNull​(T obj, Supplier<String> messageSupplier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T,java.util.function.Supplier))

or

- [`Objects.requireNonNullElse​(T obj, T defaultObj)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNullElse(T,T)) vs
- [`Objects.requireNonNullElseGet​(T obj, Supplier<? extends T> supplier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNullElseGet(T,java.util.function.Supplier))

or

- [`Optional.orElse​(T other)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElse(T)) vs
- [`Optional.orElseGet​(Supplier<? extends T> supplier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet(java.util.function.Supplier))

or

- [`log​(System.Logger.Level level, String msg)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.Logger.html#log(java.lang.System.Logger.Level,java.lang.String)) vs
- [`log​(System.Logger.Level level, Supplier<String> msgSupplier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.Logger.html#log(java.lang.System.Logger.Level,java.util.function.Supplier))

Comment: your last point should be read by lots of logger implementors, it's been 7 years since java-8 is out and I still have loggers where `log.isDebugEnalbed()` is needed and `spring` is _full_ with such statements; instead of simply providing a `Supplier` as argument

Comment: @Eugene sounds like an issue that can be solved with code transformation. `logger.method(/*string concatenation*/)` gets compiled (JDK 9+) to *push logger, push arguments*, `invokedynamic` (string concatenation), `invoke… method`. The transformator only has to replace the two invocations with a single `invokedynamic` with a custom bootstrap method that consumes *logger* and *arguments*. The custom bootstrap method only needs to get a handle to the original method and prepend the condition check.

Comment: that is a great idea, with the downside that all these libs are still stuck in java-8 world. thank you for the hint